# How do I download all plots from my shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I would like users to be able to upload a file, see the graphs displayed and then offer them a download link where they can download all graphs as pdfs in a zip or tar file. I have managed to do all steps except for the last. It works for one graph but not for many. 
Here is my code

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  #takes the uploaded file and transforms it into the way I want it

  dataInput<-reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile))  return(NULL)
    data<-read.csv(inFile$datapath, fileEncoding="UTF-16", sep="\t")
    data$date<-ymd(data$StartDate)
    data$date2<-format(data$date,"%b %y")
  })

  #plot 1
  plotInput1<-function(){
    data <- dataInput()
    dataByCountry<-aggregate(Queries~date+Category, sum,data=data)
    ggplot(dataByCountry, aes(x=date, y=Queries, group=Category, color=Category))+geom_line(size=1.5)+

  }
  #plot 2
  plotInput2<-function(){
    data <- dataInput()
    categoryQueries<-aggregate(Queries~date+Geo+Category, sum,data=data)
    ggplot(categoryQueriesLastyear, aes(x=Category, y=Queries, fill="#3369e8"))+geom_bar(stat='identity', fill="#3369e8")+
    }

  #render plots
  output$haha1 <- renderPlot({plotInput1()})
  output$haha2 <- renderPlot({plotInput2()})

  #I can download one plot but how do I donwload all of them?

  output$foo <- downloadHandler(
    filename ="graphs.pdf",
    content = function(file) {
      pdf(file, width=12, height=6.3)
      print(plotInput1()
            dev.off()
    })
})
})
```

Any help would be highly appreciated